# Catching all invalid urls in expressJS is also catching static or public files

Tags: node.js, connect, express

I am using expressJs 3.x and node 0.8.8. In my application I tried to catch all invalid urls. So I have added the following code. It is working fine, it is also catching the url, if I try to access the public or static files.

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res){
    \\ Do some action like redirecting or whatever ...
});
```

How to avoid or pass static folder files (GET Request) and how to catch only invalid urls ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely, you're calling `app.use(app.router)` prior to `app.use(express.static(...))`, so that `express` tries to find matching route first, and only if there is no matched route it tries to find the corresponding static files.

The configuration code should be like that:

```
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(app.router);
});
```

so that `express` will try to find a static file first.

Comment: Thanks it saves my time.. But this synchronous thingy has to change... expressjs have to differentiate static calls and invalid url like in other framework ROR, etc

Comment: What "synchronous thingy"? What do you call "an invalid url"? With `express` configured as in provided code example, `express` first handles the url to the `static` middleware; the middleware either serves the static file (if it exists) or handles the url to the next processor in line (if file does not exists), which is the `router` middleware; the middleware either calls your controller (if there exists a matched route) or handles the url to the next processor in line (won't happen, as you have a route `/*` that matches all urls).

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons `Express` does not differentiate between statics and non-statics, this may be a gotcha at times but it is extremely flexible.

I'm not sure what you mean by `expressjs have to differentiate static calls`, there's no such thing as an `invalid url`, it's just how you interpret an arbitrary string.